# On Android, is there a way to access all video (like a buffer) for all video played on the device? If so, can you tell me what class?

Tags: android

Do all Android apps use some universal device buffer as the video is playing? If so, how can i access the buffer?

Comment: No, I do not believe that is possible. For 1 some apps may chose a different method of media playback as opposed to using the MediaPlayer.

Comment: I will consider this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the video player streaming in Android like this:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Shadab, so i am new to Android. I am looking to access the video buffer of any app. So if a video from Vine is playing, I can access buffer. How would i do that?

Comment: Then you are handling over access to the Vine Player, if the Vine player has an access allowed to you, then you will be able to access the app's output otherwise it is not possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shadab

Comment: New account. I am unable to Mark answered yet.

Comment: Its okay fine, continues